# loop GroupBy and save keys in new list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to make a `groupBy` over a `List<CourseEvent>` and save the keys into another `List<CourseVendor>`

class **CourseEvent**:

```
public class CourseEvent : ICourseEvent
{
    // other properties
    public string Vendor { get; set; }
}
```

class **courseVendor**:

```
public class CourseVendor
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

What I tried to do was:

```
// 1) get List<CourseEvent> items
List<CourseEvent> courseEvents = LoadCourseEvents();

// 2) group items by property "Vendor"
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string,CourseEvent>> groups = courseEvents.GroupBy(c => c.Vendor).ToList();

// 3) convert to list
List<CourseEvent> courseVendors = groups.SelectMany(group => group).ToList();

// 4) initiate target class
List<CourseVendor> vendors = new List<CourseVendor>(); 

// 5) fill target class
courseVendors.ForEach(c => vendors.Add(new CourseVendor { Name = c.Vendor }));
```

That would save the Key (vendor) field into a new `List<CourseVendor>` but the thing is, because of the `.SelectMany` in line 3) the `vendor` field of each item in `courseEvents` will be written into `courseVendors`. But how can I correct it? Every `vendor` should occur only once in my `List<CourseVendor> vendors`.

Comment: Where does it save the key to a new list? You're not accessing the key of the group anywhere. Did you perhaps mean `List<Vendor> courseVendors = groups.Select(g => g.Key).ToList();` as step 3? SelectMany expands each group into all the elements of that group and is unlikely what you want.

Comment: your example was very close, I got it to work now using:

`groups.Select(g => new CourseVendor {Name = g.Key}).ToList()`;

thank you!

Comment: That will produce new vendor objects, if that's what you want.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders sorry, got it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for steps 3 through 5. Once you have your groupings, you can simply use:

```
var vendors = groups.Select(g => new CourseVendor { Name = g.Key }).ToList();
```

And if you don't have any need for the intermediate data, you could make it all a one liner:

```
var vendors = 
    LoadCourseEvents()
        .GroupBy(c => c.Vender)
        .Select(g => new CourseVendor { Name = g.Key })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry to nitpick but these will all result in a `List<string>` not a `List<CourseVendor>`. you need a `.Select(g => new CourseVendor { Name = g.Key })` or similar in each query.

Comment: @BenRobinson - Sorry. Forgot to finish that part off. Fixed it.